# Excel - Find and replace, set to value of column header

Tags: excel

I have a csv with columns that include a 'yes' or `null` value. I would like to replace each 'yes' with the name of it's column header. I know I could go through each column and F&R, but there's about 40 columns and there will be changes in the future. I would like to streamline it with a formula, but I have no idea how to F&R with a formula.

I have this:

```
service_1 | service_2 | service_3
yes       | yes       | yes
          | yes       | yes
```

I'm looking for this:

```
service_1 | service_2 | service_3
service_1 | service_2 | service_3
          | service_2 | service_3
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 'service_1' is in cell A1 and 'yes' is in cell A2, you can paste this formula in D2 and copy paste across and down to F3.  Copy your headers from A1:C1 to D1:F1 to complete your example.

```
=IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")
```

Note the absolute reference to the first row headers, **A$1**.

Don't forget to copy your new data and paste the values if you want to get rid of your original three columns (in your example).